# Save a pandor table as image

Tags: r, image, save

I have a table like:

```
 From/To (%)  0 30 60 90 NA
1           0 63 24  0  0 13
2          30 28 46 21  0  5
3          60 13 29 25  2 31
4          90  7  2  5 52 35
5          NA 93  7  1  0  0
```

I'd like to save it as a .png

```
png("C:/exp/test.png", height=1000, width=200)
pandoc.table(a, justify='right', style='simple',emphasize.rownames=T,
             digits= '2')

dev.off()
```

But I got an empty file.

How can I save it as an image and also with no extra margin (no blank spaces)?

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify `print` (not tested)

Comment: Since pander evaluation happens when you knit the file (using pandoc), I'm not sure `print` would produce what you expect - the return from pandoc.table is raw markdown, not a nicely formatted table. I honestly think your best option is to knit it as usual, and take a high resolution screenshot...

Comment: @gaby-p do you want to save the **markdown** table as an image?

Comment: @daroczig, hi. Yes. I need to save it as an image but with no extra blank space

Comment: @GabyP IMHO there's no full-blown solution for this, but you could start a graphic device with the appropriate width/height computed by the number of characters in the `pandoc.table.return` table (consider that as a matrix of chars), and simply render those with base `text` or other functions on your graphic device.